# Using html files instead of dot files with doT.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node application and i'm using express and the [doT.js](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html) template engine.

Everything is working but my template views have to be files with the extension `.dot`. I would prefer to have my views be html files because html is more ubiquitous.

Here is some of my current code:

```
var app = express()

app.engine('dot', express_dot.__express);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './public/dot_views'));
app.set('view engine', 'dot');
```

what can I add or change so that my views don't have to be `.dot` files and can be `.html` files instead?

Comment: Try `app.engine('html', express_dot.__express); ... app.set('view engine', 'html');`

Comment: @cartant hey that worked. Wanna post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need to do is rename the view engine identifier from `dot` to `html`, as that's what express is using for the file extension:

```
app.engine('html', express_dot.__express);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './public/dot_views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

You are configuring the engine explicitly, so, as long as it's changed in both places, express will match up the `html` `view engine` with the doT engine you've configured as `html`.